# python36-devel vs python3-dev

Tags: python, python-3.6, centos7

What is the difference between `python3-dev` and `python36-devel`?

**context:** in the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) on building Tensorflow from source, it says I must install `python-dev` or `python3-dev`. However, I can't find anything `python3-dev`. Instead, I get results about `python3-devel`. So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: I think `-dev` is Debian/Ubuntu naming convention and `-devel` is RedHat/Centos style for the same thing. Both are packages of files necessary to develop new software. Not 100% sure, that's why I'm posting it as a comment only.

Comment: on RHEL 7 ami, python3-devel is not there. you just have to build it or get it from rhel

Comment: I have the same question. I build a docker image from `amazoncorretto:8` (which is based on CentOS). Previously, I `yum -y install python3-dev`, then I can install python packages. Recently, my build failed because of missing `Python.h`. I had to additionally install `python3-devel`. Is there a name change?

Comment: Note that if you install python3-dev while you have python3.6 in your system, the installation might upgrade your python version to another one (e.g. 3.7.). I am facing this problem right now and python36-devel is unavailable in my system :(